# Copy and Paste options are not working in Gedit text-editor in a Linux terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, touchpad, gedit, asterisk

I'm new to Ubunto and Linux. I'm using Ubunto 20.04 Virtual Machine, and I'm trying to install asterisk using the terminal.
There are some codes that I need to write in text files using **gedit**, but instead of rewriting the codes I want to copy them and paste them on gedit.
None of the following is working for me:
Ctrl + v
Ctrl + shift + v
Alt + Insert
Ctrl + Insert
Shift + Insert
**I also noticed that when the terminal asks me to enter my password, It doesn't show it on the terminal as I write it. I don't know if that's related.**

Comment: "**I don't know if that's related**" - it's not: see [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Comment: Being specific as to which of the 20+ terminals you are using may help... You haven't mentioned if you're talking Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS or something else but the mention of `gedit` implies desktop, but it's still best if we're told rather than making assumptions (that maybe wrong).

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubunto 20.04 LTS Desktop, also I just realized all the shortcuts don't work.

Comment: It can be bugs in ubuntu 20.04 that have not been fixed. Several times it happens to me as well. Similar with this problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241475/cut-paste-or-copy-paste-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04-on-using-right-click-context