# Can't paste files into a Windows directory while using Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 22.04, sudo, copy

I can't copy files or folders from Ubuntu 22.04 to a Windows partition [D:]

[image: a preview of access denied]

As you noticed I was able to do that, but I reinstalled Ubuntu on an SSD instead of HDD, maybe because the first time I made an  efi and swap partition when installing Ubuntu the first time. I really don't know what the problem is from, although it wasn't there before. I'm using simple copy/paste shortcuts or the mouse.

Comment: Have you disabled fast start in Windows?

Comment: I really don't recall doing that but i'll try doing it and see
but i'm on Ubuntu not Windows
So i really don't know how would this help
i'll do it anyways and see

Comment: Actually it worked 
So i put the method and mentioned you there 
Thanks a punch <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed

Simply Disable the fast StartUp in Windows

simply open windows CMD as an Administrator and write:

```
powercfg /h off
```

This will simply turn off the fast StartUp and fix the issue

[credits:[{user68186}](https://askubuntu.com/users/68186/user68186) [and a web page](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht513773-how-to-enable-or-disable-fast-startup-on-windows-11)]